# Issue creating JSONObject with Instagram API response

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, instagram

I have made a call to the Instagram Endpoint for images that contain the tag #selfie. The issue I am having is in dealing with the response. I get a massive JSON Response, and all I really need is the "thumbnail" image "url".

How can I go about structuring an Object from the Data that is in the JSONObject?

```
public static class FetchTaggedImages extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {


    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
        String mAccessToken = params[0];
        String url = (API_URL + "?access_token=" + mAccessToken);
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String instagramJSONResponse = null;
        JSONArray responseArray = null;
        HttpResponse postResponse;

        try {
            postResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            instagramJSONResponse = EntityUtils.toString(postResponse
                    .getEntity());
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(instagramJSONResponse);
            String thumbnail = jsonObject.getString("url");

            responseArray = new JSONArray(instagramJSONResponse);
            Log.e("RESPONSE", instagramJSONResponse);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responseArray;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        Log.e("ONPOSTEXECUTE", "ONPOSTEXECUTE");

        JSONObject jsonObject;


    }
}
```

**HERE IS A SAMPLE OF THE JSON STRING**

```
    {  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "summer",
            "love",
            "tagstagram",
            "colorful",
            "instalike",
            "selfie",
            "swag",
            "instago",
            "igers",
            "follow4follow",
            "follow",
            "instadaily",
            "friends",
            "style",
            "webstagram",
            "look",
            "instafollow",
            "iphoneonly",
            "instagood",
            "amazing",
            "instacool",
            "bestoftheday",
            "fun",
            "followme",
            "like4like",
            "picoftheday",
            "photooftheday"
         ],
         "location":null,
         "link":"http:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/wFlirqPxAW\/",
         "user_has_liked":false,
         "caption":{  
            "id":"866263615190011927",
            "created_time":"1417486691",
            "text":"First contest of the season ",
            "from":{  
               "id":"507279035",
               "profile_picture":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_507279035_75sq_1397511894.jpg",
               "username":"jdbv45",
               "full_name":"Juan Basave"
            }
         },
         "type":"image",
         "id":"866263614401482774_507279035",
         "likes":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "id":"956576929",
                  "profile_picture":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10802992_1561400387426348_1634151041_a.jpg",
                  "username":"don_assi2014",
                  "full_name":"-Ali Assi-"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"520771011",
                  "profile_picture":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/1889350_1565133803717465_1353157813_a.jpg",
                  "username":"michelle.y6",
                  "full_name":"Michelle Y"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"873300277",
                  "profile_picture":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10817804_1543101285933854_123980756_a.jpg",
                  "username":"ayah_shahbanderr",
                  "full_name":"Ayah"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"199966711",
                  "profile_picture":"https:\/\/igcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/10617174_587781691338392_1164910966_a.jpg",
                  "username":"elijah_reissman_",
                  "full_name":"Elijah Reissman"
               }
            ],
            "count":13
         },
         "images":{  
            "low_resolution":{  
               "url":"http:\/\/scontent-b.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xap1\/t51.2885-15\/1739913_754468237961901_1189124740_a.jpg",
               "height":306,
               "width":306
            },
            "standard_resolution":{  
               "url":"http:\/\/scontent-b.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xap1\/t51.2885-15\/1739913_754468237961901_1189124740_n.jpg",
               "height":640,
               "width":640
            },
            "thumbnail":{  
               "url":"http:\/\/scontent-b.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xap1\/t51.2885-15\/1739913_754468237961901_1189124740_s.jpg",
               "height":150,
               "width":150
            }
         },
         "users_in_photo":[  

         ],
         "created_time":"1417486691",
         "user":{  
            "id":"507279035",
            "profile_picture":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_507279035_75sq_1397511894.jpg",
            "username":"jdbv45",
            "bio":"",
            "website":"",
            "full_name":"Juan Basave"
         },
         "filter":"Mayfair",
         "comments":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "id":"866282245801841449",
                  "created_time":"1417488912",
                  "text":"#TagStaGram #love #friends @tagstagram #photooftheday #selfie #amazing #followme #follow4follow #like4like #look #instalike #igers #picoftheday #instadaily #instafollow #fun #iphoneonly #instagood #bestoftheday #instacool #instago #summer #follow #webstagram #colorful #style #swag",
                  "from":{  
                     "id":"507279035",
                     "profile_picture":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_507279035_75sq_1397511894.jpg",
                     "username":"jdbv45",
                     "full_name":"Juan Basave"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "count":1
         },
         "attribution":null
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

"thumbnail" is in "images" object, and "images" object is in a first object of the "data" array.

So you need to obtain the "data" JSONArray first, access for each array item, find "images" object from the item, and finally you can access "thumbnail" object.

Your code seems to access to "url" in the top level object that does not have "url" property.

If you'd like to access via JSONObject framework, you should implement the code like this:

```
public String getUrl(JSONObject response) throws JSONException {
  JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("data");
  JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(0);
  JSONObject images = object.getJSONObject("images");
  JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject("thumbnail");
  return thumbnail.getString("url");
}
```

If you need a collection of the url, you need to iterate accessing all data objects like this:

```
JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(0);
  // ...
}
```

This is a basic function for dealing with JSON string that Android Framework provides.
If you feel that it is a long way to go, consider using GSON or Jackson JSON Processor.